# $\mathbb{Q}$-forms of $\operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ inside $\operatorname{SL}_8(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be the image of the natural embedding of $\operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ inside $\operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb{C})\subset \operatorname{SL}_8(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\mathbf{G}$ is an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{Q})$ being $\mathbb{Q}$-isotropic.

My question: is it possible to find $g\in \operatorname{SL}_8(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g\mathbf{G}g^{-1}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic and $\mathbb{Q}$-**anisotropic**?

Comment: Do you know of an example of this happening, e.g. for $SL_2$?

Comment: The "natural embedding" is $A\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} A & 0\\  0 & I_4\end{pmatrix}$ or $A\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} A & 0\\  0 & A\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @YCor the second one $A\to \begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & A 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Vincent Yes for $\operatorname{SL}_2$ this happens. It can be obtained using a quaternionic central division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Intruiging. I knew there was a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$-forms of $SL_2$ and quaternion-algebras, but I thought that conjugating left everything isomorphic, so you wouldn't get to a truly different algebra/group. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Vincent I think that the difference is that we allow conjugacy by $\operatorname{SL}_8(\mathbb{R})$, instead of just $\operatorname{SL}_8(\mathbb{Q})$, such that the resulting group is $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic. This yields, in principle, different isomorphism classes over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I think I have to see an example in order to understand it, so I really hope someone can type an answer. So far I cannot phantom how $x \mapsto g^{-1}xg$ can *not* be a bijective group homomorphism, no matter what bigger group $g$ comes from.

Comment: @Vincent Consider rational quadratic forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$ of signature $2+1$. Their orthogonal groups are $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic and conjugate over $\mathbb{R}$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}$ in general as some of them are $\mathbb{Q}$-isotropic and some are not. This also happens for $\operatorname{SL}_2$ acting on $2\times 2$ matrices i.e there are $\mathbb{Q}$-isotropic $\mathbb{Q}$-forms conjugate in $\operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ to anisotropic ones.

Comment: I find it a bit easier to think about Lie algebras than groups. I can see how you have two Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that are non-isomorphic while their 'realifications' $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R} := \mathfrak{g} \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathfrak{h}_\mathbb{R} := \mathfrak{h} \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$$ *are* isomorphic. (Ctd in next comment)

Comment: Now if you have very concrete embeddings of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ into $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{R})$, then we can realize $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathfrak{h}_\mathbb{R}$ also in a very concrete way: as the set of all $\mathbb{R}$-linear combinations of the elements of $\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{h}$ respectively. I also see how there must be some $g \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ such that for these concrete versions $\mathfrak{h}_\mathbb{R} = g^{-1}\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}g$. But what I don't get is how that would imply $\mathfrak{h} = g^{-1}\mathfrak{g}g$ for the same $g$.

Comment: I.e. for most $X \in \mathfrak{h}$ wouldn't $g^{-1}Xg$ be some linear combination of elements of $\mathfrak{g}$ that is not in $\mathfrak{g}$ itself? Or is this different for groups than for Lie-algebras?

Comment: I'm sorry you came here to ask a question and now I am asking you questions, but I really find this whole set-up fascinating and hope to learn something here

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for pointing this out. The general situation should be as follows (If I understand correctly your argument): we have two algebras $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}}, \mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and  embeddings of $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{R}}$ into some $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ which are conjugate over $\mathbb{R}$. But we want also the embeddings of $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}}, \mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ to be conjugate over $\mathbb{R}$ to embeddings into $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ (this is the whole point).

Comment: Continuation of the previous comment: comparing to our situation $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathfrak{sl}(4,\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ should be some anisotropic $\mathbb{Q}$-form of $\operatorname{SL}_4(\mathbb{R})$. The embeddings of $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{R}}$ are into $\mathfrak{sl}(8,\mathbb{R})$.... (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: Ah wait you want them to be conjugate to embeddings into $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{Q})$! I thought you wanted them to be conjugate to *eachother*. Now I get it, thank you!

Comment: The question is about Galois cohomology. We have a subgroup ${\bf G}={\rm SL}_{4, {\Bbb Q}}$ and an embedding $\iota\colon {\bf G}\hookrightarrow {\bf H}$ where   ${\bf H}={\rm SL}_{8, {\Bbb Q}}$.

Comment: Can you compute the normalizer of ${\bf G}(\Bbb C)$ in  ${\bf H}(\Bbb C)$ and the action of this normalizer on  ${\bf G}(\Bbb C)$ ? Then I will answer your question.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi the normalizer has two components: one is the group of block-diagonal matrices $(A,B)$ with $\det(A,B)=1$, $A,B\in\mathrm{GL}_4$. The other one contains the flip. The action is the obvious one by conjugation.

Comment: @YCor: I think we need $B=\lambda A$ for some scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Oops, I computed the normalizer of the wrong group. Actually, the normalizer is bigger than that. Indeed, the centralizer in the matrix algebra is a copy of $M_2(\mathbf{C})$, so in $\mathrm{GL}_8$ it can be identified to $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{C})$, and in $\mathrm{SL}_8$ this corresponds to matrices in $A\in\mathrm{GL}_2$ with $\det(A)^4=1$. The normalizer is thus generated by this and the given copy of $\mathrm{SL}_4$ (no element of the normalizer acts as non-inner automorphism) — they intersect in scalar matrices $\lambda I_8$, $\lambda^4=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\nN}{{\mathcal N}}
\newcommand{\SL}{{\rm SL}}
\newcommand{\G}{{\bf G}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\Bbb Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\Bbb R}}
\newcommand{\C}{{\Bbb C}}
$The answer is **No**.

Write $\nN$ for the normalizer of $\G$ in $\SL_{8,\Q}$.
We wish to find an anisotropic $\Q$-subgroup $\G'\in\SL_{8,\Q}$ such that
$\G'_\R$ is conjugate to $\G_\R$ under $\SL(8,\R)$.
Then $\G'\simeq{} _c \G$ for some 1-cocycle $c\in Z^1(\Q,\nN)$ such that $c$ becomes a coboundary in $ Z^1(\R,\nN)$.
Since $\nN$ acts on $\G$ by *inner* automorphisms
(see a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456984/mathbbq-forms-of-operatornamesl-4-mathbbr-inside-operatornamesl#comment1184403_456984) of @YCor above),
we see that $\G'$ must be an anisotropic *inner form* of $\G$
with an 8-dimensional representation defined over $\Q$.

Any inner form $\G'$ of $\G=\SL_{4,\Q}$ is isomorphic to $\SL(1,D)$ where
$D$ is a central simple algebra of degree 4 over $\Q$.
Since $\G'$ is anisotropic, $D$ is a division algebra.
However, a representation $\rho$ of $\G'=\SL(1,D)$ over $\Q$ such that $\rho\otimes_\Q\C$ contains the standard 4-dimensional representation of $\G'_\C\simeq\SL_{4,\C}$ in $\C^4$, has dimension at least 16.
Thus there is no anisotropic $\Q$-subgroup $\G'\subset\SL_{8,\Q}$ conjugate to $\G$ over $\R$ or over $\C$.